# Variable inductor

Tags: inductor, flyback

How can I design a variable inductor with a closed core? It should be used in flyback topology so I need it to be a low leakage. My idea is to use rectangle shape (CI core.) One leg will be movable and ground diagonally so that one side of the leg will have a different thickness than the other.

[image]

Edit:

The second option:

[image]

Edit:
I tried to use a core with different cross section area according mean path. Seems the inductance is the same if the turns are posioned in thick or thin part od core.

[image]

A current rise(slope):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *How to design a variable inductor with closed core?*

My first point is that a flyback transformer normally requires a gap so, without a gap the following parameters will need to be justified: -

- H field calculations for all positions would be needed and,
- B field calculations to check the possibility of excessive core saturation (likely without a gap).

In addition to the above, the likelihood of a smooth transition from one inductance value to the next as you slide the tapered \$I\$ piece is almost nil. I witnessed an experiment with a \$UI\$ core set where the wrong face of the \$I\$ piece (not quite so well machined but not obviously so to the eye) mated up with the \$U\$ core and the inductance dropped from about 700 μH to about 300 μH.

This is a massive change and, I calculated that this was equivalent to a net gap of less than 0.1 mm.

Hence, keeping the faces extremely smooth is going to be an almost impossible task. I would suggest that you use a gap (likely needed anyway) and vary that gap.

Comment: You are right. I already measure it and the gap has much more impact then core diameter.

Comment: What do you think about toroidal core solution i added. Will it change inductance as core rotates?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický no it won't change the inductance because all the magnetic field is in the core and, no matter what angle that core is moved to the net flux will be the same.